# Azure Cognitive Search: Stop white-spaces to act like separator

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We have some PDF files in azure storage and indexing is applied on it. when azure searched is performed using single search keyword e.g.

> /docs?search=TG105&searchFields=content&highlight=content

it will return snippet of all the places where keyword TG105 is found. This result is expected so its good.

But when searched is performed with a full sentence e.g.

> /docs?search=What is TG105&searchFields=content&highlight=content

it will return the text snippets where each single keyword `what`, `is`, `TG105` is found separately in the content.

lets say there is a sentence `SIM card is not inserted` it will return in highlight list as `SIM card <em>is</em> not inserted.`

Now the question is how to do full sentence search, so that it highlight only where **"what is TG105"** is found?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your search phrase inside quotation marks ([Phrase search operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax#phrase-search-operator)) so your query should be something like:

> /docs?search=**"What is TG105"**&searchFields=content&highlight=content

This will return all documents containing this exact phrase (case insensitive) and the following higlight:

```
{
...
"@search.highlights": {
            "content": [
                "whatever <em>What</em> <em>is</em> <em>TG105</em> whatever"
            ]
        }
...
}
```

**Important**: You will not get results for documents containing something like this:

> What is ***the*** TG105

To take care about this is time to play with `queryType=full`and full lucene syntax [Proximity search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-4-proximity-search)